# Using the override keyword on implementations of abstract methods

Tags: scala

Is it good practice to use the `override` keyword when implementing abstract methods defined in traits?

```
trait Tooth {
  def ache(): Unit
}

class Molar extends Tooth {
  override def ache(): Unit = {}
}
```

In the above example, I understand that the override keyword is optional; but is it advisable? On which side of the terseness vs. safety trade-off should I fall?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`override` does one thing for you there: when removing `Tooth.ache` but not its implementations later on, you will get compiler errors. In particular, this forces implementations of `Tooth` (written by yourself or others) to be "close" to `Tooth` in a certain sense, namely that deprecated methods vanish (or are at least reconsidered).

This may or may not be desired.

Comment: OTOH, if somebody someday puts an implementation of `ache` inside `Tooth`, aiming to provide _the_ eventual final solution, he/she will not even know that there will still be old implementations in the code.

Comment: I agree with this. I have seen numerous examples of dead code because an abstract method was renamed.

Answer (score 15):

Personally, when I see

```
override def whatever()
```

the first thing I think is, "I wonder how this was supposed to behave before?"

Since this is an unhelpful thought if it was an abstract method, I find it both more terse *and* more safe to leave it off.

Answer (score 12):

I usually don't use override when implementing an abstract method. It's not wrong, but redundant, and I prefer to keep my code as short as possible while maintaining clarity. But I realize it's not a clear-cut case.

Answer (score 8):

I always use it, to indicate member that were declared on super classes, even if abstract.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer (by far), but it limits itself by being too brief. I would add that an override has a much distinct *intention* from a regular method (a new method only adds behavior; an override potentially changes it). And whenever different intention is needed, it is best to make it explicit.

Comment: OTOH, if somebody someday puts an implementation of ache inside Tooth, aiming to provide the eventual final solution, he/she will not even know that there will still be old implementations in the code.